# Converting formData to forms.Form in django

Tags: ajax, django

I would like to allow user to key in a quiz code and gets an alert to tell whether if the code is still invalid without refreshing the page. I already read a lot of Django AJAX and JQuery tutorials but most of them seem outdated because they do not cover the part where csrf token must be send.

In my settings.py, I set CSRF_USE_SESSIONS to True.

This is my forms.py

```
class codeForm(forms.Form): 
    code = forms.IntegerField(label='Question Code')
```

In my html file, I have this

```
<form class="card__form" id="code-form" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}                                <script type="text/javascript">                                 // using jQuery                             
var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();                             </script>                                       {{form.as_p}
<center><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary card__submit" id="submit_code"></center>
```

Just before the  tag, I have this :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit_code").click(function(){
            alert("Text: ");

            event.preventDefault();

            var myform = document.getElementById("code-form");
            var form = new FormData(this);

            form.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrftoken);

            $.ajax({
            data : form,
            dataType:'json',
            type: 'POST',
            method: 'POST',
            url: '{% url 'student:process_code' %}',

            contentType: false,
            processData: false,

            success: function(context) {
                alert(context.msg);
            },
            error: function(context) {
                alert(context.msg);
            }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

In my views.py

```
def process_code(request):
    context = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = codeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            code = cd.get('code')
            print('yay')
            if code.isdigit():
```

The unexpected result was the form is not valid (form.is_valid() = false). Thus, I think my formData object is not converted to a valid forms.Form type.
I also tried to use form = codeForm(request.POST['code']) but it return more error.

How can I get around this? I prefer not to use serialize() because I read that it cannot be used for uploading files which will be my next feature to work on after this has settled. I wanted to use forms.Form because it has cleaned_data method. If you could provide a good solution although not using forms.Form but with good reasoning, I will appreciate it. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

try FormData(myform), not "this"

Comment: It would help to explain why they should not use `this`.

Comment: Right. To my understanding, you instantiate the object with the wrong parameter (submit code button)